# Using environment variables post docker container linking in java

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to simulate docker container linking using a simple use case which is as follows

1) A docker container with a simple pub-sub java application, there is a publisher and subscriber both within the same container. I have used dockerfiles for building this
2) A docker container running rabbitmq, this was pulled from docker hub.

Now I link both the containers, I am able to see rabbitmq environment variables in my container #1.

Now my question is what is the best way to utilize these container variables in my pub-sub container #1. I can always java System.getenv and hardcode a environment variable. Are there any better ways of doing it?

Comment: Its unclear what you are asking. A good way of reading variables?

Comment: Hello Usman, Let me elaborate more....My java application needs the host and port of rabbitmq to successfully connect to rabbitmq. When I link the containers rabbitmq details will be available in my container running java applicaiton. Now my java application will have a line of code which says factory.setHost("HOSTNAME"). My question is what are the best ways of setting this host name. Definitely I do not want to hardcode. I hope this clarifies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard-coding an environment variable seems OK here.  The environment variables follow a standard format, like `RABBITMQ_PORT_5672_TCP_ADDR` and `RABBITMQ_PORT_5672_TCP_PORT`.  The only bit of those names which would change is the label `RABBITMQ`, which is set based on the options to `docker run`. Whoever runs your container controls that bit, either with `--link rabbitmq` or `--link someothercontainer:rabbitmq` to set an alias.  This just forms part of your container's "contract" with the outside world: the container must be run in a way that adds variables with the right alias.

Incidentally, this doesn't force you to use Docker links if you don't want to, as you can always just pass in the environment variables if Rabbit MQ were on a different machine (e.g. `--env RABBITMQ_PORT_5672_TCP_ADDR=1.2.3.4`).